# How can I validate these variables without an if else statement?

Tags: c#

I'm very new to c# so please excuse my lack of knowledge. I'm just trying to check the following:

- "CardNumberLength" = 16
- "CardPINLength" = 3
- "CardNameHasSpace" 0
  I don't want to use an if else statement, is there another way?

The code:

```
public bool Validate()
{
    CardNumberLength = Convert.ToString(GetCardNumber()).Length;

    CardPINLength = Convert.ToString(GetCardPIN()).Length;

    CardNameHasSpace = GetCardName().IndexOf(" ");
}
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use if? Its natural to use it to check **IF** something is ok.

Comment: Instead of `Convert.ToString(expr)` you can often use `expr.ToString()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just return the boolean result:

```
return CardNumberLength == 16 && CardPINLength == 3 && CardNameHasSpace >= 0;
```

Comment: My apologies, i should have said that i want it to check all 3 of these values, and if they are all correct (as listed in the description), i want it to return "true", if not, "false".

Comment: Exactly this happens in that statement :) Please note that `=` is an assignment and `==` is a comparison.

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely had to do this without if tests, you could mash them together in a return statement. It's just a different syntax to express the same logic. I probably wouldn't suggest doing this without if tests though.

```
public bool Validate()
{
    return Convert.ToString(GetCardNumber()).Length == 16 //replaces CardNumberLength
        && Convert.ToString(GetCardPin()).Length == 3 // replaces CardPINLength
        && GetCardName().IndexOf(" ") < 1; // replaces CardNameHasSpace
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    public bool Validate()
    {
        int CardNumberLength = int.Parse(GetCardNumber().ToString().Length);
        int CardPINLength = int.Parse(GetCardPIN().ToString().Length);
        bool CardNameHasSpace = GetCardName().Contains(" ");
        
        return CardNumberLength == 16 && CardPINLength == 3 && !CardNameHasSpace
    }
```

using the .ToString() on an object is way better than Convert.ToString(), also you can check inside a string if it contains a certain string with the .Contains(string) function on a string.

Comment: You’re assigning ToString().Length to a string…

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow I believe that breaks the `return` statement too

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow yea i was sort of not paying attention when i was writing that, i fixed it now

Answer (score -3):

```
public bool Validate()
{
    CardNumberLength = Convert.ToString(GetCardNumber()).Length;
    CardPINLength = Convert.ToString(GetCardPIN()).Length;
    CardNameHasSpace = GetCardName().IndexOf(" ");

    return CardNumberLength == 16 && CardPINLength == 3 && CardNameHasSpace > -1;
}
```

Or

```
public bool Validate()
{
   CardNumberLength = Convert.ToString(GetCardNumber()).Length;
   CardPINLength = Convert.ToString(GetCardPIN()).Length;
   CardNameHasSpace = GetCardName().IndexOf(" ");

   if (CardNumberLength != 16)
      return false;
      
   if (CardPINLength != 3)
      return false;
      
   if (CardNameHasSpace == -1)
      return false;
  
   return true;
}
```

Perhaps, this helps you :)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you. I didn't know about the try, catch function in C# just yet.

Comment: Throwing the exception seems kind of needless. At that point you might as well just return false

Comment: Please [don't use exceptions as control flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729379/why-not-use-exceptions-as-regular-flow-of-control).

Comment: I've just replaced the throw exception with return false and it does the job

Comment: @AlexGottschalk This uses if tests though

Comment: Sometimes OPs really don't know to explain what they are looking for. If it helps them, it helps them

Comment: @AlexGottschalk please mark the answer that helped and close the thread

Comment: @PasanRatnayake Even if they don't know how to explain it exactly, that is still a really bad idea.

Comment: I begun 2 days ago, so all code is helpful to me, even if it is deemed as wrong. I'm also new to this website, how do I close the tread xD

Comment: @AlexGottschalk I'm just sayin, this is a pretty key time for you to not learn bad habits.

Comment: @AlexGottschalk don't worry about it. Sometimes people forget who we are supposed to help. A moderator would probably close it soon.

Comment: @Dortimer thank you very much for your help :)